# Howto edit TopLevelHeaderTemplates PART_Popup in Expression Blend

Tags: wpf, popup, expression-blend

I am very new to Expression Blend but can't find any solution with google. I would like to style a Menu and it's items. But how can I see the actual look of the PART_Popup? The IsOpen Property is bound to something like {Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}. It seems I am only looking at something complete invisible :). There is also a SystemDropShadowChrome but I actually can't see this thing. The eyes next to all the items are active. And even if I change some background colors all that I see is just a black transparent rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a toolkit control (dropdownmenu) or a telerik (radmenu) or something? If you've already broken out the template (eg; Right click->Edit Template->Edit Current/Copy) Then there's a couple things you want to try to find it since sometimes they can be oddly embedded.

Go to the root level of the control, try Right Click->Edit Additional Templates->...

If that' doesn't provide your part_ look in your broken out template resource you've created and inspect your object tree. You're looking for embedded controls appearing as objects. Right click the embedded control in your object tree and edit its template (Current or Copy)

You'll potentially sometimes have to drill down multiple layers within a template to expose the objects you wish you to edit. If you specify which control you're working with I'm sure we can tell you exactly how to get to where you need more efficiently. Cheers!

Comment: Its the default .NET 4 WPF Menu/MenuItem.

Comment: Finally got a spare minute to look at this and luckily it's a piece of cake. I was a bit confused when you were emphasizing the part_popup but I couldn't recall the template structure at the time. Anyway here's what you do;

Comment: Right Click your Menu control, Choose "Edit Additional Templates" -> "(ItemContainerStyle)" -> "Edit A Copy" and check out your rectangle objects. They have their visibility set to visible, and their opacity at 100% BUT if you choose the "Bg" for example, notice the R G B A next to the color palette in your properties panel, change the A to 100% to set your alpha and change the Fill color. You'll notice the change immediately. Run your app and your sub-menu will have the color you set. So it's just misleading because there's nothing immediately visible. So you're not actually concerned with...

Comment: part_popup, you want your ItemContainerStyle. Edit the ItemContainerStyle objects and States to get the effect you want and your menuitems will be styled accordingly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh also, when you "Edit a copy" of a style, its best to create a new resource dictionary to save your styles to. Then you can come back and easily access this menuitemstyle easily from your Resources tab -> the resourcedictionaryname.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Try exploring the States tab. Most likely some of the parts are only visible in certain states.